# How to find the index for a given item in a list?

Tags: python, list, indexing

Given a list `["foo", "bar", "baz"]` and an item in the list `"bar"`, how do I get its index `1`?

Comment: Are you returning:

[1] The lowest index in case there are multiple instances of `"bar"`,
[2] All the indices of `"bar"`?

Comment: a) Is it guaranteed that item is in the list, or else how we should handle the error case? (return None/ raise ValueError) b) Are list entries guaranteed to be unique, and should we return the first index of a match, or all indexes?

Comment: View the answers with numpy integration, numpy arrays are far more efficient than Python lists. If the list is short it's no problem making a copy of it from a Python list, if it isn't then perhaps you should consider storing the elements in numpy array in the first place.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question (in protest) because there are already 42 undeleted answers (and 16 more deleted) for a simple, one-liner reference question that almost all have the same built-in function at their core (as they should, because it's the only reasonable and sane approach to the problem and everything surrounding it is just error-checking or creatively re-interpreting the specification, which still only leaves one other reasonable, sane approach to the expanded problem).

Comment: There is no realistic chance of a better approach becoming possible in future versions of Python, because the existing approach is already just calling a single, built-in method on the list - as simple as it gets.

Answer (score 5977, accepted):

```py
>>> ["foo", "bar", "baz"].index("bar")
1
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) for the built-in `.index()` method of the list:

> ```
> list.index(x[, start[, end]])
> ```
>
> Return zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is equal to *x*. Raises a [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) if there is no such item.
>
> The optional arguments *start* and *end* are interpreted as in the [slice notation](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) and are used to limit the search to a particular subsequence of the list. The returned index is computed relative to the beginning of the full sequence rather than the start argument.

### Caveats

#### Linear time-complexity in list length

An `index` call checks every element of the list in order, until it finds a match. If the list is long, and if there is no guarantee that the value will be near the beginning, this can slow down the code.

This problem can only be completely avoided by using a different data structure. However, if the element is known to be within a certain part of the list, the `start` and `end` parameters can be used to narrow the search.

For example:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('l.index(999_999)', setup='l = list(range(0, 1_000_000))', number=1000)
9.356267921015387
>>> timeit.timeit('l.index(999_999, 999_990, 1_000_000)', setup='l = list(range(0, 1_000_000))', number=1000)
0.0004404920036904514
```

The second call is orders of magnitude faster, because it only has to search through 10 elements, rather than all 1 million.

#### Only the index of the *first match* is returned

A call to `index` searches through the list in order until it finds a match, and *stops there.* If there could be more than one occurrence of the value, and all indices are needed, `index` cannot solve the problem:

```
>>> [1, 1].index(1) # the `1` index is not found.
0
```

Instead, use a [list comprehension or generator expression to do the search](/questions/34835951/), with [`enumerate` to get indices](/questions/522563/):

```
>>> # A list comprehension gives a list of indices directly:
>>> [i for i, e in enumerate([1, 2, 1]) if e == 1]
[0, 2]
>>> # A generator comprehension gives us an iterable object...
>>> g = (i for i, e in enumerate([1, 2, 1]) if e == 1)
>>> # which can be used in a `for` loop, or manually iterated with `next`:
>>> next(g)
0
>>> next(g)
2
```

The list comprehension and generator expression techniques still work if there is only one match, and are more generalizable.

#### Raises an exception if there is no match

As noted in the documentation above, using `.index` will raise an exception if the searched-for value is not in the list:

```
>>> [1, 1].index(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 2 is not in list
```

If this is a concern, either [explicitly check first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934190) using `item in my_list`, or handle the exception with `try`/`except` as appropriate.

The explicit check is simple and readable, but it must iterate the list a second time. See [What is the EAFP principle in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858) for more guidance on this choice.

Comment: index returns the first item whose value is "bar". If "bar" exists twice at list, you'll never find the key for the second "bar". See documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: If you're only searching for one element (the first), I found that `index()` is just under 90% faster than list comprehension against lists of integers.

Comment: What data structure should be used if the list is very long?

Comment: @izhang: Some auxillary index, like an {element -> list_index} dict, if the elements are hashable, and the position in the list matters.

Comment: sequence1 = sorted(sequence2, key=.sequence3.index) is a very handy idiom. You may use index more often if that's in your repertoire.

Comment: that's true, @mpoletto... What can be done in that case of having multiple same values???

Comment: @jvel07, see the list/generator comprehension examples in my answer.

Comment: Raising an exception seems like a poor design choice in hindsight.

Answer (score 713):

The majority of answers explain how to find **a single index**, but their methods do not return multiple indexes if the item is in the list multiple times. Use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, j in enumerate(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']):
    if j == 'bar':
        print(i)
```

The `index()` function only returns the first occurrence, while `enumerate()` returns all occurrences.

As a list comprehension:

```
[i for i, j in enumerate(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']) if j == 'bar']
```

---

Here's also another small solution with [`itertools.count()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) (which is pretty much the same approach as enumerate):

```
from itertools import izip as zip, count # izip for maximum efficiency
[i for i, j in zip(count(), ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']) if j == 'bar']
```

This is more efficient for larger lists than using `enumerate()`:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "from itertools import izip as zip, count" "[i for i, j in zip(count(), ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']*500) if j == 'bar']"
10000 loops, best of 3: 174 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "[i for i, j in enumerate(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']*500) if j == 'bar']"
10000 loops, best of 3: 196 usec per loop
```

Comment: Enumeration works better than the index-based methods for me, since I'm looking to gather the indices of strings using 'startswith" , and I need to gather multiple occurrences. Or is there a way to use index with "startswith" that I couldn't figure out

Comment: In my hands, the enumerate version is consistently slightly faster. Some implementation details may have changed since the measurement above was posted.

Comment: This was already answered since '11: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list

Comment: In Python 3 `izip` should be replaced by the built in `zip`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32659581/15422118)

Comment: This is a good solution and it's much more flexible than the accepted solution. For example, if you only are expecting to have 1 value in the list, you can add a if statement to raise an exception `if len([i for i, j in enumerate(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']) if j == 'bar']) > 1` otherwise you could just return `[i for i, j in enumerate(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']) if j == 'bar'][0]`

Answer (score 242):

To get all indexes:

```
indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(xs) if x == 'foo']
```

Comment: There's already another question for this, added in '11: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list

Answer (score 158):

`index()` returns the **first** index of value!

> |  index(...)
>    |      L.index(value, [start, [stop]]) -> integer -- return first index of value

```
def all_indices(value, qlist):
    indices = []
    idx = -1
    while True:
        try:
            idx = qlist.index(value, idx+1)
            indices.append(idx)
        except ValueError:
            break
    return indices

all_indices("foo", ["foo","bar","baz","foo"])
```

Comment: And if doesn't exist in the list?

Comment: Not-exist item will raise ValueError

Comment: This answer would fit better here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list

Answer (score 110):

```
a = ["foo","bar","baz",'bar','any','much']

indexes = [index for index in range(len(a)) if a[index] == 'bar']
```

Answer (score 109):

A problem will arise if the element is not in the list. This function handles the issue:

```
# if element is found it returns index of element else returns None

def find_element_in_list(element, list_element):
    try:
        index_element = list_element.index(element)
        return index_element
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Answer (score 74):

You have to set a condition to check if the element you're searching is in the list

```
if 'your_element' in mylist:
    print mylist.index('your_element')
else:
    print None
```

Comment: This helps us to avoid try catch!

Comment: However, it might double the complexity. Did anybody check?

Comment: @stefanct Time complexity is still linear but it will iterate through the list twice.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish That is obviously what I meant. Even if pedantically it is the same *order* of complexity, iterating twice might be a severe disadvantage in many use cases thus I brought it up. And we still don't know the answer...

Comment: @stefanct this likely does double the complexity, I believe the `in` operator on a list has linear runtime. @ApproachingDarknessFish stated it would iterate twice which answers your question, and is right in saying that doubling the linear complexity is not a huge deal. 
I wouldn't call iterating over a list twice a severe disadvantage in many use cases, as complexity theory tells us that O(n) + O(n) -> O(2*n) -> O(n), ie- the change is typically neglibile.

Answer (score 63):

If you want all indexes, then you can use [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy):

```
import numpy as np

array = [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1]
item = 1
np_array = np.array(array)
item_index = np.where(np_array==item)
print item_index
# Out: (array([0, 2, 6], dtype=int64),)
```

It is clear, readable solution.

Comment: What about lists of strings, lists of non-numeric objects, etc... ?

Comment: This answer should be better posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list

Comment: This is the best one I have read. numpy arrays are far more efficient than Python lists. If the list is short it's no problem making a copy of it from a Python list, if it isn't then perhaps the developer should consider storing the elements in numpy array in the first place.

Answer (score 57):

> ### Finding the index of an item given a list containing it in Python
>
> For a list `["foo", "bar", "baz"]` and an item in the list `"bar"`, what's the cleanest way to get its index (1) in Python?

Well, sure, there's the index method, which returns the index of the first occurrence:

```
>>> l = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
>>> l.index('bar')
1
```

There are a couple of issues with this method:

- if the value isn't in the list, you'll get a `ValueError`
- if more than one of the value is in the list, you only get the index for the first one

#### No values

If the value could be missing, you need to catch the `ValueError`.

You can do so with a reusable definition like this:

```
def index(a_list, value):
    try:
        return a_list.index(value)
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

And use it like this:

```
>>> print(index(l, 'quux'))
None
>>> print(index(l, 'bar'))
1
```

And the downside of this is that you will probably have a check for if the returned value `is` or `is not` None:

```
result = index(a_list, value)
if result is not None:
    do_something(result)
```

#### More than one value in the list

If you could have more occurrences, you'll **not** get complete information with `list.index`:

```
>>> l.append('bar')
>>> l
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bar']
>>> l.index('bar')              # nothing at index 3?
1
```

You might enumerate into a list comprehension the indexes:

```
>>> [index for index, v in enumerate(l) if v == 'bar']
[1, 3]
>>> [index for index, v in enumerate(l) if v == 'boink']
[]
```

If you have no occurrences, you can check for that with boolean check of the result, or just do nothing if you loop over the results:

```
indexes = [index for index, v in enumerate(l) if v == 'boink']
for index in indexes:
    do_something(index)
```

#### Better data munging with pandas

If you have pandas, you can easily get this information with a Series object:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> series = pd.Series(l)
>>> series
0    foo
1    bar
2    baz
3    bar
dtype: object
```

A comparison check will return a series of booleans:

```
>>> series == 'bar'
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Pass that series of booleans to the series via subscript notation, and you get just the matching members:

```
>>> series[series == 'bar']
1    bar
3    bar
dtype: object
```

If you want just the indexes, the index attribute returns a series of integers:

```
>>> series[series == 'bar'].index
Int64Index([1, 3], dtype='int64')
```

And if you want them in a list or tuple, just pass them to the constructor:

```
>>> list(series[series == 'bar'].index)
[1, 3]
```

Yes, you could use a list comprehension with enumerate too, but that's just not as elegant, in my opinion - you're doing tests for equality in Python, instead of letting builtin code written in C handle it:

```
>>> [i for i, value in enumerate(l) if value == 'bar']
[1, 3]
```

### Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/239121)?

> The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Why do you think you need the index given an element in a list?

If you already know the value, why do you care where it is in a list?

If the value isn't there, catching the `ValueError` is rather verbose - and I prefer to avoid that.

I'm usually iterating over the list anyways, so I'll usually keep a pointer to any interesting information, getting the [index with enumerate.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/522563/541136)

If you're munging data, you should probably be using pandas - which has far more elegant tools than the pure Python workarounds I've shown.

I do not recall needing `list.index`, myself. However, I have looked through the Python standard library, and I see some excellent uses for it.

There are many, many uses for it in `idlelib`, for GUI and text parsing.

The `keyword` module uses it to find comment markers in the module to automatically regenerate the list of keywords in it via metaprogramming.

In Lib/mailbox.py it seems to be using it like an ordered mapping:

```
key_list[key_list.index(old)] = new
```

and

```
del key_list[key_list.index(key)]
```

In Lib/http/cookiejar.py, seems to be used to get the next month:

```
mon = MONTHS_LOWER.index(mon.lower())+1
```

In Lib/tarfile.py similar to distutils to get a slice up to an item:

```
members = members[:members.index(tarinfo)]
```

In Lib/pickletools.py:

```
numtopop = before.index(markobject)
```

What these usages seem to have in common is that they seem to operate on lists of constrained sizes (important because of O(n) lookup time for `list.index`), and they're mostly used in parsing (and UI in the case of Idle).

While there are use-cases for it, they are fairly uncommon. If you find yourself looking for this answer, ask yourself if what you're doing is the most direct usage of the tools provided by the language for your use-case.

Answer (score 56):

All of the proposed functions here reproduce inherent language behavior but obscure what's going on.

```
[i for i in range(len(mylist)) if mylist[i]==myterm]  # get the indices

[each for each in mylist if each==myterm]             # get the items

mylist.index(myterm) if myterm in mylist else None    # get the first index and fail quietly
```

Why write a function with exception handling if the language provides the methods to do what you want itself?

Comment: The 3rd method iterates twice over the list, right?

Comment: Re: *"All of the proposed functions here"*: At the time of writing perhaps, but you ought to check newer answers to see if it is still true.

Answer (score 35):

#### Getting all the occurrences and the position of one or more (identical) items in a list

With enumerate(alist) you can store the first element (n) that is the index of the list when the element x is equal to what you look for.

```
>>> alist = ['foo', 'spam', 'egg', 'foo']
>>> foo_indexes = [n for n,x in enumerate(alist) if x=='foo']
>>> foo_indexes
[0, 3]
>>>
```

#### Let's make our function findindex

This function takes the item and the list as arguments and return the position of the item in the list, like we saw before.

```
def indexlist(item2find, list_or_string):
  "Returns all indexes of an item in a list or a string"
  return [n for n,item in enumerate(list_or_string) if item==item2find]

print(indexlist("1", "010101010"))
```

---

**Output**

---

```
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

### Simple

```
for n, i in enumerate([1, 2, 3, 4, 1]):
    if i == 1:
        print(n)
```

Output:

```
0
4
```

Comment: This answer should be better posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list

Answer (score 34):

```
me = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
me.index("bar")
```

You can apply this for any member of the list to get their index

Answer (score 27):

All indexes with the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
get_indexes = lambda x, xs: [i for (y, i) in zip(xs, range(len(xs))) if x == y]

print get_indexes(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 3, 2])
print get_indexes('f', 'xsfhhttytffsafweef')
```

Comment: This answer should be better posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list

Comment: `enumerate(xs)` is clearer than `zip(xs, range(len(xs))`. Also, this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 26):

Simply you can go with

```
a = [['hand', 'head'], ['phone', 'wallet'], ['lost', 'stock']]
b = ['phone', 'lost']

res = [[x[0] for x in a].index(y) for y in b]
```

Answer (score 22):

Another option

```
>>> a = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'red']
>>> b = 'red'
>>> offset = 0;
>>> indices = list()
>>> for i in range(a.count(b)):
...     indices.append(a.index(b,offset))
...     offset = indices[-1]+1
... 
>>> indices
[0, 3]
>>>
```

Comment: This answer should be better posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Answer (score 22):

## And now, for something completely different...

... like confirming the existence of the item before getting the index.  The nice thing about this approach is the function always returns a list of indices -- even if it is an empty list.  It works with strings as well.

```
def indices(l, val):
    """Always returns a list containing the indices of val in the_list"""
    retval = []
    last = 0
    while val in l[last:]:
            i = l[last:].index(val)
            retval.append(last + i)
            last += i + 1   
    return retval

l = ['bar','foo','bar','baz','bar','bar']
q = 'bar'
print indices(l,q)
print indices(l,'bat')
print indices('abcdaababb','a')
```

When pasted into an interactive python window:

```
Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def indices(the_list, val):
...     """Always returns a list containing the indices of val in the_list"""
...     retval = []
...     last = 0
...     while val in the_list[last:]:
...             i = the_list[last:].index(val)
...             retval.append(last + i)
...             last += i + 1   
...     return retval
... 
>>> l = ['bar','foo','bar','baz','bar','bar']
>>> q = 'bar'
>>> print indices(l,q)
[0, 2, 4, 5]
>>> print indices(l,'bat')
[]
>>> print indices('abcdaababb','a')
[0, 4, 5, 7]
>>>
```

## Update

After another year of heads-down python development, I'm a bit embarrassed by my original answer, so to set the record straight, one can certainly use the above code; however, the *much* more idiomatic way to get the same behavior would be to use list comprehension, along with the enumerate() function.

Something like this:

```
def indices(l, val):
    """Always returns a list containing the indices of val in the_list"""
    return [index for index, value in enumerate(l) if value == val]

l = ['bar','foo','bar','baz','bar','bar']
q = 'bar'
print indices(l,q)
print indices(l,'bat')
print indices('abcdaababb','a')
```

Which, when pasted into an interactive python window yields:

```
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2017, 11:07:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def indices(l, val):
...     """Always returns a list containing the indices of val in the_list"""
...     return [index for index, value in enumerate(l) if value == val]
... 
>>> l = ['bar','foo','bar','baz','bar','bar']
>>> q = 'bar'
>>> print indices(l,q)
[0, 2, 4, 5]
>>> print indices(l,'bat')
[]
>>> print indices('abcdaababb','a')
[0, 4, 5, 7]
>>>
```

And now, after reviewing this question and all the answers, I realize that this is exactly what [FMc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55857/fmc) suggested in his [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python/17300987#17300987).  At the time I originally answered this question, I didn't even *see* that answer, because I didn't understand it.  I hope that my somewhat more verbose example will aid understanding.

If the single line of code above still *doesn't* make sense to you, I highly recommend you Google 'python list comprehension' and take a few minutes to familiarize yourself.  It's just one of the many powerful features that make it a joy to use Python to develop code.

Answer (score 20):

Here's a two-liner using Python's `index()` function:

```
LIST = ['foo' ,'boo', 'shoo']
print(LIST.index('boo'))
```

Output: `1`

Answer (score 17):

A variant on the answer from FMc and user7177 will give a dict that can return all indices for any entry:

```
>>> a = ['foo','bar','baz','bar','any', 'foo', 'much']
>>> l = dict(zip(set(a), map(lambda y: [i for i,z in enumerate(a) if z is y ], set(a))))
>>> l['foo']
[0, 5]
>>> l ['much']
[6]
>>> l
{'baz': [2], 'foo': [0, 5], 'bar': [1, 3], 'any': [4], 'much': [6]}
>>>
```

You could also use this as a one liner to get all indices for a single entry. There are no guarantees for efficiency, though I did use set(a) to reduce the number of times the lambda is called.

Comment: This answer should be better posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list

Answer (score 16):

Finding index of item x in list L:

```
idx = L.index(x) if (x in L) else -1
```

Comment: This iterates the array twice, thus it could result in performance issues for large arrays.

Comment: @Cristik - Correct. Not suitable if there is no reasonably low upper bound available for the list length.

Comment: Should be used only for non-repetitive tasks/deployments, or if the list length is relatively small enough to not affect overall performance noticeably.

Answer (score 14):

This solution is not as powerful as others, but if you're a beginner and only know about `for`loops it's still possible to find the first index of an item while avoiding the ValueError:

```
def find_element(p,t):
    i = 0
    for e in p:
        if e == t:
            return i
        else:
            i +=1
    return -1
```

Answer (score 12):

List comprehension would be the best option to acquire a compact implementation in finding the index of an item in a list.

```
a_list = ["a", "b", "a"]
print([index for (index , item) in enumerate(a_list) if item == "a"])
```

Comment: Works nicely for integers and floats too, as well as finding all occurrences

Answer (score 11):

Python `index()` method throws an error if the item was not found. So instead you can make it similar to the `indexOf()` function of JavaScript which returns `-1` if the item was not found:

```
def indexof( array, elem):
try:
    return array.index(elem)
except ValueError:
    return -1
```

Comment: however, _JavaScript_ has the philosophy that weird results are better than errors, so it makes sense to return -1, but in Python, it can make a hard to track down bug, since -1 returns an item from the end of the list.

Comment: -1 is not a weird result in java/javascript. It is a language convenction of "not found in list". It is possible to use this java intelligence in Python doing a simple verification:
if theindex > -1: or if theindex >= 0: which does the same.

Answer (score 11):

There is a chance that that value may not be present so to avoid this ValueError, we can check if that actually exists in the list .

```
list =  ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

item_to_find = "foo"

if item_to_find in list:
      index = list.index(item_to_find)
      print("Index of the item is " + str(index))
else:
    print("That word does not exist")
```

Comment: Calling a variable `list` overwrites a builtin function. Calling `in`, then `index` means you're doing two searches. Better to `try`/`except` `.index()` as suggested in other threads.

Answer (score 9):

It just uses the python function `array.index()` and with a simple Try / Except it returns the position of the record if it is found in the list and return -1 if it is not found in the list (like on JavaScript with the function `indexOf()`).

```py
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']

try:
  pos = fruits.index("mango")
except:
  pos = -1
```

In this case "mango" is not present in the list `fruits` so the `pos` variable is -1, if I had searched for "cherry" the `pos` variable would be 2.

Answer (score 8):

There is a more functional answer to this.

```
list(filter(lambda x: x[1]=="bar",enumerate(["foo", "bar", "baz", "bar", "baz", "bar", "a", "b", "c"])))
```

More generic form:

```
def get_index_of(lst, element):
    return list(map(lambda x: x[0],\
       (list(filter(lambda x: x[1]==element, enumerate(lst))))))
```

Comment: This answer feels at home for `Scala` / *functional-programming* enthusiasts

Comment: When only a single value is needed in a list that has many matches this one takes long.

Answer (score 8):

#### For one comparable

```py
# Throws ValueError if nothing is found
some_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].index('baz')
# some_list == 2
```

#### Custom predicate

```py
some_list = [item1, item2, item3]

# Throws StopIteration if nothing is found
# *unless* you provide a second parameter to `next`
index_of_value_you_like = next(
    i for i, item in enumerate(some_list)
    if item.matches_your_criteria())
```

#### Finding index of all items by predicate

```py
index_of_staff_members = [
    i for i, user in enumerate(users)
    if user.is_staff()]
```

Comment: `idx = next((i for i, v in enumerate(ls) if v == chk), -1)` to get the behavior similar to str.index(chk).

Comment: @tejasvi88 Decided to put some extra work into the answer

Answer (score 7):

```
name ="bar"
list = [["foo", 1], ["bar", 2], ["baz", 3]]
new_list=[]
for item in list:
    new_list.append(item[0])
print(new_list)
try:
    location= new_list.index(name)
except:
    location=-1
print (location)
```

This accounts for if the string is not in the list too, if it isn't in the list then `location = -1`

Answer (score 6):

Since Python lists are zero-based, we can use the zip built-in function as follows:

```
>>> [i for i,j in zip(range(len(haystack)), haystack) if j == 'needle' ]
```

where "haystack" is the list in question and "needle" is the item to look for.

(Note: Here we are iterating using i to get the indexes, but if we need rather to focus on the items we can switch to j.)

Comment: [i for i,j in enumerate(haystack) if j==‘needle’] is more compact and readable, I think.

Answer (score 5):

## If performance is of concern:

It is mentioned in numerous answers that the built-in method of `list.index(item)` method is an O(n) algorithm. It is fine if you need to perform this once. But if you need to access the indices of elements a number of times, it makes more sense to first create a dictionary (O(n)) of item-index pairs, and then access the index at O(1) every time you need it.

If you are sure that the items in your list are never repeated, you can easily:

```
myList = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

# Create the dictionary
myDict = dict((e,i) for i,e in enumerate(myList))

# Lookup
myDict["bar"] # Returns 1
# myDict.get("blah") if you don't want an error to be raised if element not found.
```

If you may have duplicate elements, and need to return all of their indices:

```
from collections import defaultdict as dd
myList = ["foo", "bar", "bar", "baz", "foo"]

# Create the dictionary
myDict = dd(list)
for i,e in enumerate(myList):
    myDict[e].append(i)

# Lookup
myDict["foo"] # Returns [0, 4]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to find an index once then using "index" method is fine. However, if you are going to search your data more than once then I recommend using [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module. Keep in mind that using bisect module data must be sorted. So you sort data once and then you can use bisect.
Using [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module on my machine is about 20 times faster than using index method.

Here is an example of code using Python 3.8 and above syntax:

```
import bisect
from timeit import timeit

def bisect_search(container, value):
    return (
      index 
      if (index := bisect.bisect_left(container, value)) < len(container) 
      and container[index] == value else -1
    )

data = list(range(1000))
# value to search
value = 666

# times to test
ttt = 1000

t1 = timeit(lambda: data.index(value), number=ttt)
t2 = timeit(lambda: bisect_search(data, value), number=ttt)

print(f"{t1=:.4f}, {t2=:.4f}, diffs {t1/t2=:.2f}")
```

Output:

```
t1=0.0400, t2=0.0020, diffs t1/t2=19.60
```

Comment: "Using bisect module on my machine is about 20 times faster than using index method." is a somewhat inaccurate way to describe the relationship between the two algorithms. It's not a linear relationship, so on small lists of, say, 10 elements, both algorithms should perform about the same. On slightly larger lists, you may begin to notice a difference. On massive lists, binary search may be thousands of times faster.

Answer (score 5):

I find this two solution is better and I tried it by myself

```
>>> expences = [2200, 2350, 2600, 2130, 2190]
>>> 2000 in expences
False
>>> expences.index(2200)
0
>>> expences.index(2350)
1
>>> index = expences.index(2350)
>>> expences[index]
2350

>>> try:
...     print(expences.index(2100))
... except ValueError as e:
...     print(e)
... 
2100 is not in list
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

For those coming from another language like me, maybe with a simple loop it's easier to understand and use it:

```
mylist = [
    "foo", "bar", 
    "baz", "bar"
]
for index, item in enumerate(mylist):
    if item == "bar":
        print(index, item)
```

I am thankful for *[So what exactly does enumerate do?](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/5087f2d786a27b02000041a9)*. That helped me to understand.

Comment: It's only an example to understand how you can find repeated items - enumerate helps to do it.

Comment: @ggorlen I understood you about **newlist** variable that I used to define the result of `enumerate(mylist)`. That's why I cut that line and put **enumerate** function on loop. And it's better now. Remembering that all everything is an object in Python, but you can call **enumerate** as "built-in" function as official documentation does, of course. And, when I use enumerate to put a list in order, I continue having a list. Otherwise, you would need to call it a dictionary, which is not the case.

Answer (score 4):

```
text = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
target = "bar"

[index for index, value in enumerate(text) if value == target]
```

> For a small list of elements, this would work fine. However, if the
> list contains a large number of elements, better to **apply binary
> search with O(log n) runtime complexity**
> .

Comment: You can only binary search if the list is sorted, and sorting is O(n log(n)).

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code:

```
["foo", "bar", "baz"].index("bar")
```

Refer to: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by @TerryA, many answers discuss how to find *one* index.

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) is a third-party library with tools to locate *multiple* indices within an iterable.

**Given**

```
import more_itertools as mit


iterable = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "ham", "foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

**Code**

Find indices of multiple observations:

```
list(mit.locate(iterable, lambda x: x == "bar"))
# [1, 5]
```

Test multiple items:

```
list(mit.locate(iterable, lambda x: x in {"bar", "ham"}))
# [1, 3, 5]
```

See also more options with [`more_itertools.locate`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.locate).  Install via [`> pip install more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools).

Answer (score 3):

Let’s give the name `lst` to the list that you have. One can convert the list `lst` to a `numpy array`. And, then use [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to get the index of the chosen item in the list. Following is the way in which you will implement it.

```
import numpy as np

lst = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]  #lst: : 'list' data type
print np.where( np.array(lst) == 'bar')[0][0]

>>> 1
```

Comment: Does not work if the item is an instance of a class

Answer (score 2):

Certain structures in python contains a index method that works beautifully to solve this question.

```
'oi tchau'.index('oi')     # 0
['oi','tchau'].index('oi') # 0
('oi','tchau').index('oi') # 0
```

References:

[In lists](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index)

[In tuples](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index)

[In string](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index)

Answer (score 1):

using dictionary , where process the list first and then add the index to it

```
from collections import defaultdict

index_dict = defaultdict(list)    
word_list =  ['foo','bar','baz','bar','any', 'foo', 'much']

for word_index in range(len(word_list)) :
    index_dict[word_list[word_index]].append(word_index)

word_index_to_find = 'foo'       
print(index_dict[word_index_to_find])

# output :  [0, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Pythonic way would to use `enumerate` but you can also use [`indexOf`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.indexOf) from `operator` module. Please note that this will raise [`ValueError` if `b` not in `a`.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/operator.py#L179)

```
>>> from operator import indexOf
>>>
>>>
>>> help(indexOf)
Help on built-in function indexOf in module _operator:

indexOf(a, b, /)
    Return the first index of b in a.

>>>
>>>
>>> indexOf(("foo", "bar", "baz"), "bar") # with tuple
1
>>> indexOf(["foo", "bar", "baz"], "bar") # with list
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Amazingly, [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)'s fallback value second parameter mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604802/python-finding-an-element-in-a-list#comment116866572_3785811) in a duplicate thread hasn't been shown here yet.

The basic `.index()` works well when you can compare whole objects, but it's common to need to search a list of objects or dicts for a particular item by a certain property, in which case a generator with a condition is the natural choice:

```py
>>> users = [{"id": 2, "name": "foo"}, {"id": 3, "name": "bar"}]
>>> target_id = 2
>>> found_user = next(x for x in users if x["id"] == target_id)
>>> found_user
{'id': 2, 'name': 'foo'}
```

This stops at the first matching element and is reasonably succinct.

However, if no matching element is found, a `StopIteration` error is raised, which is a little awkward to deal with. Luckily, `next` offers a second parameter `next(gen, default)` fallback to provide a more natural, `except`-free control flow:

```py
>>> found_user = next((x for x in users if x["id"] == target_id), None)
>>> if not found_user:
...     print("user not found")
... 
user not found
```

This is a bit more verbose, but still fairly readable.

If an index is desired:

```py
>>> found_idx = next((i for i, x in enumerate(users) if x["id"] == 1), None)
>>> found_idx
None
>>> next((i for i, x in enumerate(users) if x["id"] == 3), None)
1
```

As [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list/76245607#comment103542321_49093542) points out, it may be best not to return the typical -1 for a missing index, since that's a valid index in Python. Raising is appropriate if `None` seems odd to return.

These are a bit verbose, but feel free to bury the code in a helper function if you're using it repeatedly, providing an arbitrary predicate.

```py
>>> def find(it, pred):
...     return next((x for x in it if pred(x)), None)
...
>>> find(users, lambda user: user["id"] == 2)
{'id': 2, 'name': 'foo'}
>>> print(find(users, lambda user: user["id"] == 42))
None
>>> find("foobAr", str.isupper) # works on any iterable!
'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't. If you absolutely need to, use the `.index(item...)` method on list. However, it takes linear time, and if you find yourself reaching for it, you are probably misusing lists to do something you should not do with them.

Most likely, you care either about 1) a two-way mapping between integers and items, or 2) about finding an item in a *sorted* list of items.

For the first one, use a pair of dictionaries. If you want a library that does this for you, use the `bidict` library.

For the second one, use methods that can properly make use of the fact that the list is sorted. Use the built-in `bisect` module in python.

If you find yourself wanting to insert items in a sorted list, you should also not use a sorted list. Either weaken the sorted requirement to a heap using the builtin  `heapq` module, or use the `sortedcontainers` library.

It is bad practice to use a data structure that is not designed for what you want to do. Using one that matches the task you give it will both telegraph to the reader that you want to do that specific thing, and also make your solution a lot faster/more scalable in practice.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution in python:

```
li1=["foo","bar","baz"]
for i in range(len(li1)):
     if li1[i]=="bar":
          print(i)
```

The data type of the list elements is irrelevant. Just replace the "bar" with the element you are looking for. We can also write a function for this as:

```
def indexfinder(element,lis):
    for i in range(len(lis)):
        if lis[i]==element:
            return i
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest ways to find the index of an element in a list is to do as follows

```js
arr = ["foo", "bar", "baz"] 
el = "bar"
try:
  index = arr.index(el)
  return index
except:
  return 'element not found'
```

Answer (score 0):

A function "indexof" similar to another languages that returs -1 if the element is not found can be written like

```
def indexof (obj, elem, offset=0):
    if elem in obj[offset:]:
        return offset + obj[offset:].index(elem)
    return -1


obj = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "foo"]

print (indexof(obj, "not here"))
print (indexof(obj, "baz"))
print (indexof(obj, "foo", 1))
```

which returns

```
-1
2
3
```

or an optimized version for big lists

```
def indexof (obj, elem, offset=0):
    if offset == 0:
       # no need of a sublist
       if elem in obj:
          return obj.index(elem)
       return -1

    sublist = obj[offset:]
    if elem in sublist:
        return offset + sublist.index(elem)
    return -1
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple option:

```
a = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
[i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i].find("bar") != -1]
```

Comment: Not every element in the list is string.

Answer (score -1):

One can use zip() function to get the index of the value in the list. The code could be;

```
list1 = ["foo","bar","baz"]
for index,value in zip(range(0,len(list1)),list1):
    if value == "bar":
        print(index)
```

Comment: `zip(range(0,len(list1)),list1)` is overkill when you could just do `enumerate(list1)`

Comment: the code is an overkill